# Count AM and PM in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given this sample data set:

```
Date_Time
10/1/2011 12:05:00 AM
10/6/2011 2:25:00 AM
10/3/2011 5:59:00 AM
10/19/2011 6:01:00 PM
11/5/2011 8:30:00 PM
11/30/2011 11:59:00 PM
```

Is there a date time function in SQL server (2005 or 2008) that can count the number of records in these two time ranges? Below is the result from above data set.

Please let me know if a website that shows this as well.

```
Midnight-6:00am     6:00pm – Midnight. 
3                   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, you want the second range to go up to 11:59pm, not midnight...  Use [`DATEPART()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to get just the hour portion of the dates and use the aggregate `SUM()` to add 1 to the total for each range when it is met.  So what you need are hours between 0 and 5 (00:00 - 05:59) and 18 and 23 (18:00 - 23:59)

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, Date_Time) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  [Midnight to 6:00am],
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, Date_Time) BETWEEN 18 AND 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  [6:00pm to 11:59pm]
FROM your_table
```

#### Update

The above counts up to 05:59:59am. If this really should count up to 06:00:00, you need to also check for the individual time parts for 6:00. This might be slow.

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN
        DATEPART(hour, Date_Time) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 
        -- Look for 06:00:00 by stripping off the date portion and comparing against a character string
        OR (DATEPART(hour, Date_Time) = 6 AND DATEPART(minute, Date_Time) = 0 AND DATEPART(second, Date_Time) = 0)
      THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END
  ) AS [Midnight to 6:00am],
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour, Date_Time) BETWEEN 18 AND 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  [6:00pm to 11:59pm]
FROM your_table
```

Alternatively, it might be faster to use

```
  SUM(CASE WHEN
        DATEPART(hour, Date_Time) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 
        -- Look for 06:00:00 also
        OR CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date_Time, 108) = '06:00:00'
      THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END
  ) AS [Midnight to 6:00am],
```

Comment: Hi Mike, suppose i want to include records from midnight to 6:00am instead of 5:59AM. What would I change the script to?

Comment: As it is, it counts up to 05:59:59.  Do you really want to count up to and including exactly 06:00:00 am?  If so, it is a different script entirely.

Comment: @joe Ok, two possibilities added above to check for exactly 06:00:00

Comment: Michael, Many thanks again. I dont know where you live but if i do, i will definitely take you out for lunch. I owe you ):